# Keep CABasicAnimation running while moving to another screen

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

Here I am, stuck with what sounds like a basic issue...

I made a simple app that runs a CABasicAnimation: if I shut the app and reopen, the animation is still on going (which is perfect), BUT if I change screen in the same app and then come back, the animation has stopped (which is bad).

Any tip ti help me fixing the issue and keep the animation running while the user is on another screen from the same app ?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    swipeVC()
    myCircle()
}

    // Animated circle
func myCircle() {
    
    // Center the shape
    let center = view.center
    
    // Create back shape
    let backlayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circulationPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    
    // Designing the animated circle
    backlayer.path = circulationPath.cgPath
    backlayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    backlayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    backlayer.lineWidth = 5
    view.layer.addSublayer(backlayer)
    
    // Designing the animated circle
    shapeLayer.path = circulationPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
    
    // Add gesture recgnition to activate the circle animation
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
    
    // Adding the circle to the main view
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IOS will remove animation when the apps go to background / navigate to other page, and that's why you see "the animation has stopped".

I would suggest to save the current state of the animation (e.g. the completion ratio) when you leave the app or the page, and resume the animation once you get back, for example, in viewWillAppear or add a observer listening to UIApplicationWillEnterForeground.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    // listening to when the app will enter foreground
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(resumeAnimation), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    ...
    // when come back from other screen
    resumeAnimation()
}

private resumeAnimation() {
    // re-draw the animation based on stored state
}
```